# Django unable to read script in block

Tags: django, django-templates

I am currently working on a Django project.

For one of my applications, I have a 'private_base.html' template, with 2 blocks: 'body_block' and 'js_block'.

**private_base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/private_base.css' %}">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="sidenav">

      <!-- side navbar -->

    </div>


    <div class="main">
      {% block body_block %}

      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    {% block js_block %}

    {% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

I am extending this base template into 'search_result.html'

**search_result.html**

```
{% extends 'private_base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}

<!-- contents -->

{% endblock %}


{% block js_block %}

<script src="{% static "js/group_search.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

When I access the site, I am given the following error message:

"TemplateSyntaxError at /group/search_result/
Invalid block tag on line 41: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

I would like to ask if I am missing something, or doing something wrong that results in Django being unable to read my `<script>` when within the `{% block %}` tag, or making Django confused with the tags.

I have tried using only one `{% block %}` tag and placing `script` within the 'child' template, and the same error message shows up. When I place the `<script>` within the parent 'private_base.html' and outside any `{% block %}`, the script and website runs just fine.

Thanks~~

Comment: Try using content instead of body_block

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AkshatZala, I just tried changing 'body_block' to 'content', the same error still shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line of search_result.html is must be a {% load 'static' %}

Answer (score 1):

Add {% load static %} to the search_result.html

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
{% load static %}
```

to  **search.html** at the first line

Comment: Hi @AkshatZala, ```{% load static %}``` is already in private_base.html, changing ```{% load static %}```, to the first line of my html doc does not help either